# How to store only one response of curl command

Tags: linux, shell, curl

i want to store the output of curl command in a variable but not whole response only one value of that response
i have this curl command

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" \
  -d '{
    "name":"'"$ORG_NAME"'",
    "displayName":"'"$ORG_DISPLAY_NAME"'",
    "description":"'"$ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION"'",
    "runtimeType":"'"$RUNTIMETYPE"'",
    "analyticsRegion":"'"$ANALYTICS_REGION"'"
  }' \
  "https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/organizations?parent=projects/$PROJECT_ID"
```

when i hit this command then it will show the response look like this

```
{
  "name": "organizations/heloo/operations/keijfiejwfefekd",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.apigee.v1.OperationMetadata",
    "operationType": "INSERT",
    "targetResourceName": "organizations/heloo",
    "state": "IN_PROGRESS"
  }
}
```

so in the response i want to store this state value in a variable

Comment: Parameter expansion occurs between double quotes, not between single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" \
  -d '{
    "name":"'"$ORG_NAME"'",
    "displayName":"'"$ORG_DISPLAY_NAME"'",
    "description":"'"$ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION"'",
    "runtimeType":"'"$RUNTIMETYPE"'",
    "analyticsRegion":"'"$ANALYTICS_REGION"'"
  }' \
  "https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/organizations?parent=projects/$PROJECT_ID" | jq '.metadata.state')
```

it will work

Comment: thanks it is working